# How to wrap a HTML header and footer around a php file?

Tags: php, templates, buffer

I have this php file:

```
<?php 
require_once('core.php');
echo("Hello World!"); 
?>
```

And this template:

```
<html>
<head>
<? echo $html_head; ?>
</head>
<body>
<? echo $html_body; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In `core.php` I tried to do this:

```
<?php 
function callback($html_body) {
    ob_start();
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/template.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}

ob_start("callback");
?>
```

But it seems I cannot do `ob_start` inside an `ob_start` callback.

Is there another way to achieve this without adding additional boilerplate code at the end of the php file such as:

```
<?php
require_once('core.php');
body_start();
?>
Hello World!
<?php body_end(); ?>
```